# What decentralized open data project has the most contributors?

Tags: contributing-data

Not including projects where the contributors are all affiliated with a central entity, for example data.gov, what decentralized open data project has the most contributors by count?

Comment: depending on how you define open data project, microformats has the most data out there not on a wikipedia url...probably the most contributors, next to wikipedia too. but theres no way to confirm solid numbers.

Comment: @albert: Interesting, though I'm unable to find any solid numbers to support that claim, here are [some numbers](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-lod/2012Dec/0047.html).

Comment: i've seen the numbers before. they're massive. and only going to get bigger. only change i see is a higher usage of schema and rdfa getting dominant @ some point. still, microformats are so easy, i don't think they'll ever be not useful. i use them as base css classes to have them always prebaked in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say Wikipedia, with [21,436,641](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aWikipedians#Number_of_editors) named editors (and more anonymous editors), but there might be bigger projects.

The only other hard-numbers references I could find are [the Ohloh project](http://www.ohloh.net/), which has tons of similar data, but it is only about open source projects, not all open data.

Comment: Because open source projects are themselves independent projects, and Ohloh is just an aggregator of metadata about those projects, I don't think it is in the spirit of the question. (I think the Wikipedia answer is spot-on though.)

Comment: @MeganSquire: Ohloh has stats about each project, and even rankings, so that you can easily see what are the most active projects.

Comment: Yes, but as an owner of one of the projects listed on there, I can tell you that it's (a) full of errors including really obvious things like "what language is this project written in" and (b) no open source project has more than about 1500 contributors, which pales in comparison to wikipedia. Even if we count every Apache developer (which I have done [http://flosshub.org/content/project-roles-apache-software-foundation-dataset]), we only get an upper bound of about 10k names.

Comment: Interesting dataset! Apparently the URL got mixed with the bracket, it is http://flosshub.org/content/project-roles-apache-software-foundation-dataset